# jQuery fade in and fade out the content

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation, fade

How can i let the content sections fade in and fade out at the navigation-click?
and then how can i let a special page loaded at joining the page?

code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();       
    $('#content').children('section').hide();    
    $('#' + $(this).attr('href')).show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() to do that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //use .stop() so that the animation queue is cleared
        //show the elemet with the given href as the id
        var $target = $('#' + $(this).attr('href')).stop(true, true);

        //hide all sections under #content except the current section
        var $secs = $('#content > section').not($target).stop(true, true).filter(':visible');
        if ($secs.length) {
            $secs.fadeOut(function () {
                $target.fadeIn();
            });
        } else {
            $target.fadeIn();
        }
    });
    $('#content > section').not('#home').hide()
});
```

Comment: thank you, look at link: [link](http://nitram0598.zapto.org) but if i cahnge page it is under the ld and then it moves..do you know what i mean? how do i fix it?

Comment: do you want to fadeout the element first then show the next one

Comment: this is great..but how can i do it that one of the pages is at loading the page visible and not all

Comment: watch at link...all contents are listed at first load..then after click on navigation is just 1 title there..how can i do it that the home is the one which is shown alone at loading and not all?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43205/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-tekkzz)

Comment: @Tekkzz Are you looking to hide the all section except home initially right.? I just updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `fadeout` the elements first and then `fadeIn` the target element after to achieve your desired effect.

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#content').children('section').not('#home').hide();

  $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();       
    $('#content').children('section').stop().fadeOut();    
    $('#' + $(this).attr('href')).stop().fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you, i used something from you, now so like i do it it is great i think..but how can i do it that one of the pages is at loading the page visible and not all (watch at link in comment at the other answer!)